# Subract Additional Time from $__timeFilter

Tags: postgresql, grafana, timescaledb

I want to subtract additional time in $__timeFilter in Grafana. Like if I have selected Last 7 days, I want to run 2 queries that do a comparison one query gives me avg cpu utilization for the last 7 days and another one gives me avg cpu utilization for now() - 14d to now() - 7d.  And this is dynamic. I can get it for 6hrs, 2 days, or anything selected.

My database is TimescaleDB and Grafana version in 8.3.5

Edit
Query is

```
select avg(cpu) from cpu_utilization where $__timeFilter(timestamp)
```

Whatever is selected in the time filter in Grafana, the query is manipulated accordingly

Now with Grafana understanding this query becomes as follows. if I select the last 24hrs

```
select avg(cpu) from cpu_utilization where timestamp BETWEEN '2022-09-07 05:32:10' and '2022-09-08 05:32:10'
```

This is normal behavior. Now I wanted that if I select the last 24hrs, this query to behave as it is but an additional query becomes

```
select avg(cpu) from cpu_utilization where timestamp BETWEEN '2022-09-06 05:32:10' and '2022-09-07 05:32:10'
```

(I just don't want it for the last 24hrs, but any relative time period selected in the filter)

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658919/14817486

Comment: What is the question? How to subtract the time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [global variables `$__to` and `$__from`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__from-and-__to).

For example, `${__from:date:seconds}` will give you a timestamp in seconds. You can then subtract 7 days (= 604800 seconds) from it and use it in your query's WHERE clause. Depending on your SQL dialect, that might be by using `TIMESTAMP()`, `TO_TIMESTAMP()` or something similar. So it would look similar to this:

```sql
[...] WHERE timestamp BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(${__from:date:seconds}-604800) AND TO_TIMESTAMP(${__to:date:seconds}-604800) [...]
```

Comment: Will try this, but just one confirmation, I dont exactly want to subract by 7 days, could be 24hrs or 30days depending on whats selected. do you think that can be done by subracting $__from and $__to variables?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want to do, but you can use them for calculations. `${__to:date:seconds} - ${__from:date:seconds}` will give you the seconds between those two timestamps. You can use them in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! If I understood correctly, you could use the `timestamp` column as the reference as the grafana is already filtering by this to the comparison query. So you can get the `min(timestamp)` and `max(timestamp)` to know the limits of your period and then build something from it.

Like `min(timestamp) - INTERVAL '7 days'` would give you the start of the previous range, and `max(timestamp) - INTERVAL '7 days'` would offer the final scope.

Comment: Yes I want something like this @jonatasdp